# Is there a way for Logic Pro X scripts to communicate with each other?

Tags: javascript, logic-pro-x

Say I have a script attached to a midi Piano and a script attached to a midi Bass. Is there any way those scripts can message each other? It seems as if each script is running in its own VM.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is no way to do this, it seems they do run separately. You will probably be able to create a plugin to make it work, but I'm almost certain there is no obvious or genuine way to do this. It is odd, as it seems like it would be regular functionality for something using javascript.